# TKinter- is StringVar.trace called when the StringVar is added to a widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, trace

I have a Tkinter-using program which uses a number of `StringVar`s to track data over multiple windows. I had been using

```
myStringVar.trace('w', lambda *args: update())
```

to detect when the user changed one of these variables, either by interacting with Entries or by choosing options from an `OptionMenu`, where 'update' was a function that changed other parts of the GUI as appropriate and 'root' was . However, I found out that `update()` was called by `myStringVar.trace()` at a particular line of my code:

```
name = OptionMenu(self, self.source, self.source.get(), *root.namelist)
```

where `self.source` is the `StringVariable` in question and `root.namelist` is an ordinary List. I found this out by sandwiching the above line between two trace statments and adding a trace statement to my update function. I also confirmed that replacing the above line with

```
name = Entry(self, textvariable=self.source)
```

would not have the same result.

Trying to copy the form of my original code as much as I could, I wrote the following test code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.myStringVar = StringVar(root)
root.myStringVar.set('hello')

class myFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.source = root.myStringVar
        self.update()
        self.pack()
    def update(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children(): widget.destroy()
        name = OptionMenu(self, self.source, self.source.get(), '1','2','3')
        name.pack()

root.myframe = myFrame(root)
root.myStringVar.get()

def speak(root):
    print(root.myStringVar.get())
    root.myframe.update()
root.myStringVar.trace('w', lambda *args: speak(root))

mainloop()
```

However, when I ran this code it did not print anything unless I changed the option in the `OptionMenu`, as you would expect.

The only difference between the two cases I can think of is that in my test code the frame in which the `OptionMenu` was placed was static while in my actual code it is dynamically generated, but I don't see how this could affect the way in which the creation of an `OptionMenu` is handled.

Comment: Is it possible that the initial value of your StringVar did not exactly match any of the values in your namelist?  I would expect the OptionMenu to change the var to a valid value in that case, thus triggering your trace.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question "TKinter- is StringVar.trace called when the StringVar is added to a widget?", the answer is "no". The trace is not called when you add a stringvar to a widget.  The trace -- assuming it is a write trace -- is only called when the value of the variable changes.

The problem is likely due to the fact you're creating a method named `update`. This is a method that already exists on widgets, and is possibly called internally by various tkinter functions. Try renaming your function to something else (eg: `update_widget`).

Comment: I thought that might have been it, except when I change the traced function to something like `myStringVar.trace('w', lambda *args: print('hi'))` and eliminated the call to update altogether, I still see 'hi' printed out between the two print statements my OptionMenu is sandwiched between. Also, changing the name of the function didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i didn't catch you point. It works to me, maybe you forget a print:

```
[...]
root.myframe = myFrame(root)
#this print myStringVar content even when the value doesn't change (each time you call it):
print("main:", root.myStringVar.get()) #<-- this is the missing print, i guess

def foo(*args): #custom useless function
    """Prints "hello" each time OptionMenu selection change"""
    print("foo: hello")

def showargs(*args): #show params, useless too
    """Prints args content each time OptionMenu change"""
    print("showargs:", args)

def showcontent(*args): #finally this print myStringVar content
    """Prints myStringVar content each time OptionMenu change"""
    print("showcontent: ",root.myStringVar.get())

root.myStringVar.trace('w', foo)
root.myStringVar.trace('w', showargs)
root.myStringVar.trace('w', showcontent)
#output:
#main: hello
#after user select "1" from OptionMenu:
#showcontent:  1
#showargs: ('PY_VAR0', '', 'w')
#foo: hello
```

I added three debug methods to test myStringVar content:

- foo is useless, but is fired each time user change OptionMenu value,
- showargs shows the *args param content,
- showcontent shows myStringVar content.
- While if you're stuck because about at line 19 you'd aspect a result, you forget to print it to console or show somehow to gui(I added a print) and it works.

So you can pass myStringVar and get its contents and/or show any changes to it.

Comment: The OP acknowledged the code doesn't reproduce the problem :-\

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question now but I was having the same issue. I found that removing the parentheses from the function you're calling fixed the issue for me. So,

`myStringVar.trace('w', lambda *args: update)`

Comment: That simply causes nothing to be called in response to the trace.  It doesn't "fix" anything, it just makes the trace pointless.